# Nutrition problem - I don't undestand why my dict does not work

Tags: python, dictionary, cs50

I'm trying to solve de nutrition problem in CS50 python course and I defined my dictionary as follows:

```
fruits = [{"Name": "Apple", "Calories": "130"},
        {"Name": "Avocado", "Calories": "50"},
        {"Name": "Banana", "Calories": "110"},
        {"Name": "Cantaloupe", "Calories": "50"},
        {"Name": "Grapefruit", "Calories": "60"},
        {"Name": "Grapes", "Calories": "90"},
        {"Name": "Honeydew", "Calories": "50"},
        {"Name": "Kiwifruit", "Calories": "90"},
        {"Name": "Lemon", "Calories": "15"},
        {"Name": "Lime", "Calories": "20"},
        {"Name": "Nectarine", "Calories": "60"},
        {"Name": "Orange", "Calories": "80"},
        {"Name": "Peach", "Calories": "60"},
        {"Name": "Pear", "Calories": "100"},
        {"Name": "Pineapple", "Calories": "50"},
        {"Name": "Plums", "Calories": "70"},
        {"Name": "Strawberries", "Calories": "50"},
        {"Name": "Sweet", "Calories": "100"},
        {"Name": "Tangerine", "Calories": "50"},
        {"Name": "Watermelon", "Calories": "80"}]
```

Then I ask for user input

`item = str(input("Item: "))` 
Then loop through the dict so I can output the calories matching the fruit

```
for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit == item:
        print(fruit["Calories"])
```

My question is why this format of dict in not working. I saw solutions online and saw that it was different but my dict structure is based on the class video structure.

Comment: `fruits` is a list of dicts, `fruit` is a dict containing name and calories of one fruit. You must first retrieve the name value from the dict to compare it with the user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a string to a dictionary. Your list contains dictionaries. then you loop through it, and you are comparing each dictionary to your string value. What you want to check for, is the correct value inside each dictionary.

```
if fruit["Name"] == item:
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `item` contains name of fruit. `fruit` in your example contains object (`{"Name": "Avocado", "Calories": "50"}`, for example). They can't be equal.

Additionally, if you plan to stick with only name and calories for fruit, you could use map instead of list of maps, like so

```py
{
  "Apple": "130", 
  "Avocado": "50", 
...}
```

and skip manual search and use `fruits[item]` to get calories

Answer (score 1):

As per comment of @Proxygonn or @cafce25 (I'm not sure), I performed this problem successfully. Thanks for all your answer! You can check it out:

```
lists = [
{"fruits": "apple", "calories": "130"},
{"fruits": "avocado", "calories": "50"},
{"fruits": "banana", "calories": "110"},
{"fruits": "cantaloupe", "calories": "50"},
{"fruits": "grapefruit", "calories": "60"},
{"fruits": "grapes", "calories": "90"},
{"fruits": "honeydew melon", "calories": "50"},
{"fruits": "kiwifruit", "calories": "90"},
{"fruits": "lemon", "calories": "15"},
{"fruits": "lime", "calories": "20"},
{"fruits": "nectarine", "calories": "60"},
{"fruits": "orange", "calories": "80"},
{"fruits": "peach", "calories": "60"},
{"fruits": "pear", "calories": "100"},
{"fruits": "pineapple", "calories": "50"},
{"fruits": "plums", "calories": "70"},
{"fruits": "strawberries", "calories": "50"},
{"fruits": "sweet cherries", "calories": "100"},
{"fruits": "tangerine", "calories": "50"},
{"fruits": "watermelon", "calories": "80"},
]

s = input("Item: ").lower().strip()
for m in lists:
    if m["fruits"] in s:
        print("Calories: ",m["calories"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers above already serve the purpose but here's how I did it -

```
item = input("Item: ")
print("Calories: ", end = "")
fruits = {
"Apple" : "130",
"Avocado" : "50",
"Banana" : "110",
"Cantaloupe" : "50",
"Grapefruit" : "60",
"Honeydew Melon" : "50",
"Kiwifruit" : "90",
"Lemon" : "15",
"Lime" : "20",
"Nectarine" : "60",
"Orange" : "80",
"Peach" : "60",
"Pear" : "100",
"Pineapple" : "50",
"Plums" : "70",
"Strawberries" : "50",
"Sweet Cherries" : "100",
"Tangerine" : "50",
"Watermelon" : "80"
}

for fruit in fruits:
if fruit == item:
    print(fruits[fruit])
```